# adobe flash storage settings

Tags: flash, adobe, storage

I have recently installed Ubuntu 14.04. I want to increase the local storage, but i cannot figure it out on this operating system. I have tried everything that i have researched, i think anyway. When I go to the Global Settings in Adobe and set it to unlimited..or whatever amount, and then click Never Ask Again, it just goes back to 0. In the specific page that i want to increase the storage, when I right click..the settings box pops up, but it is unusable. I have re-installed already. Can someone help me figure this out? I am pretty unfamiliar with Ubuntu.

Comment: Clicking never ask again seems to appears to reduce the amount to none. Try NOT doing that and see if you get better results.

Comment: yes, yeah i tried that too. does not work. thank u:)

Comment: That's odd. It works for me across numerous reboots. I suggest you try again and make sure the do not ask again checkbox is NOT checked.

Answer (score 1):

1) Visit the global setting manager at http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager07.html

[image: storage-settings]

2) Choose the amount of storage you want used.

3) **Leave the do not ask again checkbox unchecked**